# ComboBox Custom Winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-8, combobox, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create a app bar in Winrt app on top with, maybe, a ComboBox. I want to do like "Bing Sport" App in Windows 8. Like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZDB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL55p.png

What's the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is write your own code.

1) Create a AppBar.

2) Create a first StackPanel for Menu with Icons(set Orientation to Horizontal)

3) Then Menu Items as Grid's or StackPanel's

4) Add a Grid or StackPanel for slide content.(set visibility to collplased)

5) Handle a Click's events. OnClick Item with Arrow do: "change clicked event style", "set item with slide content Visibility to Visible", "Add Items"

Comment: You right, the best way is to write my own code, I quickly succeeded thanks to xaml.

Thanks